# recommend HTML editor tool

Tags: text-editor

I used dreamweaver for HTML editing so far and its fine for UI developer I think.
But most weak point is too heavy.
I wonder if I should upgrade to something more lighter with full-featured.

Anyone recommend me HTML editor tool?

Those features are what I'm looking for.

- not heavy to load
- split mode (code / view)
- custom colors for element/attribue/values...
- auto-complete tag (code hint)
- auto-add close tag
- changes code same time interactively (like multiple sections.)
- html validation check
- wysiwyg

Comment: For Windows ? or for others O.S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your work on Windows (if not, let me know)

You could take a look to (All of them are WYSIWYG):

- [Microsoft Expression Web 4 (Free Version)](http://www.bluegriffon.org/) Developed by Microsoft. Not exactly WYSIWYG but quite close and quite similar to Dreamweaver for an easy transition.
- [BlueGriffon](http://www.bluegriffon.org/) Open Source
- [Aloha](http://www.aloha-editor.org/) Open Source

I like Brackets a lot, but It's not WYSIWYG as you are request for.

Answer (score 1):

For simple light weight code editor I would recommend [Bracket](http://brackets.io/) , Simply nice for HTML and Javascript coding and for split mode you can always use developer tool of browsers. I find them much better.